# SQL- Si las filas suman 1 en un grupo sumar el total

Tags: sql, group-by

Buen día amigos,

Espero puedan ayudarme, estoy intentando realizar un query que dependiendo la categoría y si la suma de una columna da como resultado 1 se sume el total.

Cualquier aporte me puede servir :)

ejemplo

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      categoria      |    categoria 2   |       valor      |       Total      |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          a          |         a        |        0.2       |        20        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          a          |         a        |        0.2       |        42        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          a          |         a        |        0.2       |        46        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          a          |         a        |        0.2       |        23        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          a          |         a        |        0.2       |         6        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          a          |         a        |        0.7       |        30        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          a          |         a        |        0.3       |        30        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          b          |         c        |        0.6       |        80        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          c          |         b        |        0.4       |        54        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          c          |         b        |        0.6       |        23        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

Como quiero que salga

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      categoria      |    categoria 2   |       valor      |       Total      |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          a          |         a        |         1        |        137       |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          a          |         a        |         1        |        60        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          c          |         b        |         1        |        77        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

Mi problema principal es que quiero que salgan todas las posibles lineas de las categorías con un valor máximo de 1

Los que no completen 1 en el valor no importa si aparecen.

Muchas gracias :)

Comment: y los que no sumen 1, deben aparecer o no?

Comment: No, esos no importan. Gracias por preguntar.

Comment: Si no importa si aparecen, no crees que sería solamente buscar la suma en cada una de las dos columnas?? ¿Que intentaste?

Comment: Hola Mariano, antes que nada gracias por tomarte tu tiempo. Mi problema es que puede que haya muchas filas de la misma columna que sumadas en conjunto me den más de 10 (por poner un ejemplo) y quiero que cada linea tenga un valor máximo de 1 por linea.

Comment: Intente con with as para sacar un preliminar pero no di con como sumar maximo hasta que den 1,

Comment: @Macarthur creo que queda más claro cuando dijiste "hasta un máximo"... Y creo que tu pregunta se podría beneficiar si incluyeras el código que intentaste, por más que no funcione.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes sumar usando la clausula `HAVING`

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.categoria
(
  categoria  CHAR(1),
  categoria2 CHAR(1),
  valor      MONEY,
  total      MONEY
)

INSERT INTO categoria VALUES ('a', 'a', 0.2, 20)
INSERT INTO categoria VALUES ('a', 'a', 0.2, 42)
INSERT INTO categoria VALUES ('a', 'a', 0.2, 46)
INSERT INTO categoria VALUES ('a', 'a', 0.2, 23)
INSERT INTO categoria VALUES ('a', 'a', 0.2, 6)
INSERT INTO categoria VALUES ('b', 'c', 0.6, 80)
INSERT INTO categoria VALUES ('c', 'c', 0.4, 54)
INSERT INTO categoria VALUES ('c', 'c', 0.6, 23)

SELECT
  c.categoria,
  c.categoria2,
  sum(c.valor),
  sum(c.total)
FROM dbo.categoria c
GROUP BY c.categoria, categoria2
HAVING sum(c.valor) = 1
```

Comment: Muchas gracias me ayudo bastante. De casualidad sabes como hacer para que de varias lineas de la misma categoría?

Comment: @Macarthur cual es el resultado requerido?